# time datatype conversion in informatica

Tags: etl, informatica

We have a character column in source `DB2` which looks like `20:10:34.272` and we have a target column in `netezza` with `TIME datatype`. When trying it load this value into the target `netezza` through informatica, it is ignoring the milliseconds part of it.

any clue about how to resolve this?

If the target column datatype is `TIMESTAMP`, milliseconds part is getting pulled perfectly, the issue is only if the datatype is `TIME`.

Comment: Can you share some code of how you are loading the data?

Comment: Hmm, had a sim. problem some time back.  After hitting our heads against the wall awhile we found it had to do with the database drivers themselves.  Possibly you have a driver issue?